# Average of groups is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My query is like this...

```
SELECT
   ClientId,
   AVG(Rate)
FROM
  Clients
GROUP BY
   ClientId
WITH ROLLUP
```

This gives...

```
NULL, 17.5769
1, 16.75
2, 17.50
3, 18.50
4, 17.50
5, 18.50
```

That's the wrong average. It should be 17.75.

What's wrong with this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how averages are calculated.  If you were to calculate an `avg` *of the group averages* you would see the `17.75` you are expecting:

```
select ClientID
        ,avg(Rate) as AvgRate
from (values(1, 16.75)
           ,(2, 17.50)
           ,(3, 18.50)
           ,(4, 17.50)
           ,(5, 18.50)
    ) as r(ClientID, Rate)
group by ClientID
with rollup;
```

## Output

```
+----------+-----------+
| ClientID |  AvgRate  |
+----------+-----------+
| 1        | 16.750000 |
| 2        | 17.500000 |
| 3        | 18.500000 |
| 4        | 17.500000 |
| 5        | 18.500000 |
| NULL     | 17.750000 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Because you are using `with rollup` it is (correctly) calculating the average of the *entire dataset* for your total value, ***which is not the same as calculating an average of the group averages.***

Answer (score 3):

The Average of an Average is not the same as a Average of all values. Take the following:

```
SELECT a,
       AVG(b) AS AvB
FROM (VALUES (1, 5.0),
             (1, 7.0),
             (2, 9.0),
             (3, 4.0),
             (3, 5.0),
             (4, 6.0)) V (a, b)
GROUP BY a;

SELECT AVG(b) AS AvAll
FROM (VALUES (1, 5.0),
             (1, 7.0),
             (2, 9.0),
             (3, 4.0),
             (3, 5.0),
             (4, 6.0)) V (a, b);

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT a,
           AVG(b) AS AvB
    FROM (VALUES (1, 5.0),
                 (1, 7.0),
                 (2, 9.0),
                 (3, 4.0),
                 (3, 5.0),
                 (4, 6.0)) V (a, b)
    GROUP BY a)
SELECT AVG(AvB) AS AvgOfAvg
FROM CTE;
```

This gives the results below:

```
a           AvB
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           6.000000
2           9.000000
3           4.500000
4           6.000000

AvAll
---------------------------------------
6.000000

AvgOfAvg
---------------------------------------
6.375000
```

Notice that the final 2 results are not the same. You are after the value in the 3rd dataset, however, the aggragation you are doing is the second.